# VB Show File/Folder Names

Tags: .net, vb.net, ienumerable, getdirectories

I am coding a programm that will run some batch files if they're selected by the user.

Each batch has its own folder in a specific "resources" folder.

I am looping through that folder to create checkboxes and labels. Everything's working fine, but I don't want the label to have the whole path - I just want to display the foldername.

CODE :

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim BatchFolder As IEnumerable = Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(appPath & "/resources")
    Dim totalNumber As Integer = Directory.GetDirectories(appPath & "/resources").Length
    Dim i As Integer = 1

    For Each dir As String In BatchFolder
        Dim Label As New Label()
        Label.Name = "Lb_" & dir
        Label.Text = dir & ".bat"
        Label.AutoSize = True
        Label.Visible = True
        Label.Location = New Point(55, 4 + 25 * i)
        Dim CustomCheckbox As New Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuCheckbox()
        CustomCheckbox.Visible = True
        CustomCheckbox.Name = "CB_" & dir
        CustomCheckbox.Checked = False
        CustomCheckbox.Location = New Point(35, 25 * i)
        CustomCheckbox.CheckedOnColor = Color.FromArgb(12, 106, 255)
        Panel5.Controls.Add(Label)
        Panel5.Controls.Add(CustomCheckbox)
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Label21.Text = totalNumber
End Sub
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of what is "whole path" and "foldername" for your case?

Comment: Hi Siva. Whole path means it shows me this: C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\xxxxxx Integr8\xxxxxx Integr8\bin\Debug\resources\Data_Type_Im

Comment: What I want it to show is only: Data_Type_Im

Comment: But in your code why you'er putting a forward slash before `resources`?

Comment: Because the desired folders/files are located in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim BatchFolder As IEnumerable = Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(appPath & "\resources")
    Dim totalNumber As Integer = Directory.GetDirectories(appPath & "\resources").Length
    Dim i As Integer = 1

    For Each dir As String In BatchFolder
        Dim Label As New Label()
        dir = dir.Substring(dir.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
        Label.Name = "Lb_" & dir
        Label.Text = dir & ".bat"
        Label.AutoSize = True
        Label.Visible = True
        Label.Location = New Point(55, 4 + 25 * i)
        Dim CustomCheckbox As New Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuCheckbox()
        CustomCheckbox.Visible = True
        CustomCheckbox.Name = "CB_" & dir
        CustomCheckbox.Checked = False
        CustomCheckbox.Location = New Point(35, 25 * i)
        CustomCheckbox.CheckedOnColor = Color.FromArgb(12, 106, 255)
        Panel5.Controls.Add(Label)
        Panel5.Controls.Add(CustomCheckbox)
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Label21.Text = totalNumber
End Sub
```

**Hope it will help you :)**

Comment: It's better to use [**`Path.GetFileName()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx). instead of extracting it yourself. `Path.GetFileName()` uses built-in methods and checks to ensure everything is done correctly, even on another system/with another path separator. Have a look at the [**`Path` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx) for an overview of all existing functions.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yeah maybe, mine it's just nerdy stuff ;).... it's just one line of code too and no error exceptions i think, but you get a vote up :)